# Some elementary relations in the quantization of a compact smooth symplectic manifold

Tags: hilbert-space, geometry, quantization

In section 6.1 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10792v1, there is a summary of relations in quantization on a compact symplectic manifold.

These relations are as follows:

1. $(M,\omega)$ compact $C^\infty$ symplectic manifold of dimension $2d$ quantize to a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ where $$\dim \mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{(2\pi\hbar)^d}\int_M\frac{\omega^d}{d!}\cdot(1+O(\hbar))$$
2. $f\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ will map to a self-adjoint operator in $\mathcal{H}$, $\hat{f}\in\text{End}(\mathcal{H})$ where $$\hat{f}\cdot\hat{g}=\widehat{fg}+\frac{i\hbar}{2}\widehat{\{f,g\}}+O(\hbar^2)$$
3. $\varphi\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$, where $|\varphi|=1$ will map to a unitary operator $\hat{\varphi}\in U(\mathcal{H})$ where $$\hat\varphi_1\cdot\hat\varphi_2=\widehat{\varphi_1\varphi_2}\cdot e^{\frac{i\hbar}{2}\{\log \varphi_1, \log \varphi_2\}+O(\hbar^2)}$$
4. $i\hbar \{\cdot,\cdot\} \simeq [\cdot,\cdot]$
5. $\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int_M\cdot \simeq \text{Tr}(\cdot)$ if $d = 1$

I just don't know the backstory of these relations. So any explanation or reference will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could elaborate on your background and current understanding

Comment: @NiharKarve I'm currently an undergraduate physics student. I know quantum mechanics at the undergraduate level and I had some free study in geometry (mostly in the concept of GR).

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to first read some introductions about geometric quantization.

Comment: @NDewolf Do you know any textbook or lecture notes you would recommend?

Comment: The References section of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+quantization has a good amount of introductions.